# Google Tag Manager - Grab nested value from data layer

Tags: google-tag-manager, data-layers

I want to grab the price key in the addToCart datalayer. It does not work by simply creating a price variable - I get the value Undefined. **How do I grab a key that is nested this deep?**

https://s22.postimg.org/f7g95zrk1/Screen_Shot_2016_11_05_at_14_09_00.png

Answer (score 1):

Create new variable with this value:

```
ecommerce.products.0.price
```

You need to use dot notation to access nested dimension.

Answer (score 1):

inserted this as a variable and just referenced the datavariable name in GTM.

ecommerce.add.products.0.price